# How to create a Debian virtual machine template?

Tags: debian, rhel, virtual-machine

Redhat documentation describes the process for sealing a virtual machine [here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Virtualization/3.5/html/Administration_Guide/sect-Sealing_Virtual_Machines_in_Preparation_for_Deployment_as_Templates.html#sect-Using_Cloud-Init_to_Automate_the_Configuration_of_Virtual_Machines)

Does anyone know of equivalent instructions for Debian and/or Ubuntu?

If not, at least some parts are straightforward to replicate:

- `# rm -rf /etc/ssh/ssh_host_*`
- `/etc/hostname` also exists in Debian and can easily be edited
- `# rm -rf /etc/udev/rules.d/70-*`
- Deleting logs in `/var/log` is straightforward

However, as far as resetting the HWADDR and UUID, I'm not sure what the Debian equivalent is for `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth*`.
Can anyone suggest any additional steps that would be advisable to seal a Debian template?